# Reading data from files and then putting it all into one list

Tags: python

I am reading data from multiple files in a directory and am using a loop to do it. When I grab the information I need it is putting it all into separate list and I am looking to print it all to the same list. When I print the list it all prints into separate list and looks as if it overrides all the other list because when I write my files to a .txt file it will only write the last list that is printed. Is there anyway to modify my code and write it all into one list?
Here is my current code:

```
for file in os.listdir():
    if file.endswith(".ls"):
        filepath = f"{path}\{file}"
        with open(filepath,'r') as monitorAxisData:

            #Reading the entire file
            monitorAxisDate = monitorAxisData.readlines()[3:4]

            #Inserting the date into a list
            dateList = []
            dateList.append(monitorAxisDate[0])

            #Joining date list
            dateListJoin = (' '.join(dateList))
            numericalDate = dateListJoin[10:20]

        
         #Reading J values
         with open(filepath, 'r') as jValues:
             j1Average = jValues.readlines()[43:53]
        
             #Creating a list for J values
             jValuesList = []
             jValuesList.append(j1Average[3])
             jValuesList.append(j1Average[4])
             jValuesList.append(j1Average[5])
             jValuesList.append(j1Average[6])
             jValuesList.append(j1Average[7])
             jValuesList.append(j1Average[8])
             jValuesList.append(j1Average[9])
        
            #Converting List to a string
            jValuesJoin = (' '.join(jValuesList))

            #Only printing the strings we need
            j1Values = jValuesJoin[10:16] #Done
            j2Values = jValuesJoin[51:57] #Done
            j3Values = jValuesJoin[92:98] #Done
            j4Values = jValuesJoin[133:139] #Done
            j5Values = jValuesJoin[174:180] #Done
            j6Values = jValuesJoin[215:221] #Done
            j7Values = jValuesJoin[256:262] #Done

            #Inserting everything into a list
            jValuesList2 = []
            jValuesList2.append(numericalDate)
            jValuesList2.append(j1Values)
            jValuesList2.append(j2Values)
            jValuesList2.append(j3Values)
            jValuesList2.append(j4Values)
            jValuesList2.append(j5Values)
            jValuesList2.append(j6Values)
            jValuesList2.append(j7Values)
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly so that it shows exactly the same indentation you have in your real code.

Comment: I edited it to show the correct indentations.

Comment: Well you have `dateList = []` inside the loop so it is reinitialized every iteration. Just define it ***outside*** (i.e. before) the loop...

Comment: Can you give some examples of how do you want your output to lookalike?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining a list, outside of the of the loop, because right now, it seems like it’s creating new lists for every iteration. If jValue2 is the finalized information that you want to keep, you can just create it before you begin the for loop.

For example:

```
jValuesList2 = []

for file in os.listdir():
    # the rest of your code
```

Then remove `jValueList2 = []` from this part of your code:

```
            # the rest of your code 

            #Inserting everything into a list

            jValuesList2.append(numericalDate)
            jValuesList2.append(j1Values)
            jValuesList2.append(j2Values)
            jValuesList2.append(j3Values)
            jValuesList2.append(j4Values)
            jValuesList2.append(j5Values)
            jValuesList2.append(j6Values)
            jValuesList2.append(j7Values)
```

These minor adjustments will make sure that everything is being saved to the same list and that the list will be available to you, outside of the for-loop.

When we define lists inside of a for-loop, each time it goes through a new iteration (a new file), it redefines the list.
That is why we have to define the final result list `jValuesList2`, before we begin iterating through files.

Comment: *"It also causes that list to only be available during the loop’s iteration"* - simply not true. Loops don't define namespaces. Any variable defined inside a loop is accessible outside of it